# Proof: Every lattice has a maximal filter iff AC

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, lattice-orders, filters, proof-explanation

I'm working through a proof of Herrlich's book *Axiom of Choice*, [p.58 (Google books)](https://books.google.de/books?id=JXIiGGmq4ZAC&lpg=PR3&ots=HKTfWKteWS&dq=herrlich%20axiom%20of%20choice&pg=PA58#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> Equivalent are
>
> 1. Every lattice has a maximal filter.
> 2. Axiom of Choice.

In this book, a *lattice* is defined as

- a poset
- in which each finite subset has an infimum and a supremum and
- there exists a smallest element $0$ and a largest element $1$
- such that $1 \neq 0$.

A *filter* $F$ is a subset of a lattice containing $1$ but not $0$, and $x,y \in F$ iff $x \land y \in F$ (I suppose $x \land y := \inf(\{x,y\})$ as the book doesn't say so explicitly).

---

In the proof of (1)$\Rightarrow$(2), the author starts off with an indexed Family of non-empty sets $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ and then considers the set $S$ of all pairs $(J,x)$ with $J \subseteq I$ and $x \in \prod_{i \in J} X_i$. The set $S$ can be made a poset by the following relation:

$$
(J,x) \leq (K,y) \iff 
(\text{$J \subseteq K$ and $y$ restricted to $J$ equals $x$}).
$$

Referring to 1. the author adds a maximal element $1$ to $S$, saying that it is now a lattice.

I can't seem to verify all axioms of a lattice. $S$ is a poset but I'm struggling with the infimum and supremum.

One way to define $(J,x) \land (K,y)$ could be as $(D(x \cap y), x\cap y)$, interpreting $x, y$ as relations (i.e. sets of ordered pairs) with domain $D(x)=J$ and $D(y)=K$.

Is this correct? How would you define the supremum, i.e. $x \lor y$?

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are "incompatible" (their union is not a function) then I guess their supremum will be $1$. Doesn't that work?

Comment: Makes sense ;-). Thanks!

Comment: I'm really surprised by that definition of filter. Almost always, one asks $F$ to be _upwards closed_, i.e. $y\geq x\in F$ implies  $y\in F$.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf You're right. It has to be $x \land y \in \mathcal{F}$ iff $x, y \in \mathcal{F}$. Correcting it right now.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf Thanks for catching that! I have to agree, this was the first time I saw filters being defined in this way.